# Enable filter format per field?

Tags: 8, entities, input-formats

Is there a simple way in Drupal 8 to set a filter format on a field and **not** show other format options that are accessible by the role of the current user?

I want to have a field with a very stripped down editor and default to that format, but I also do not want to show the formatting options on this field. I already tried the Simplify module, not quite what I am looking for.

EDIT: Sure, you can form alter... just wondering if someone solved it in a more modular way for 8.2.x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Better Formats module provides this type of functionality.

See [Better Formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_formats) Module.

> Better formats is a module to add more flexibility to Drupal's core
>   input format system.
>   **Features**
>   Set allowed text formats per field.
>  Set default order of text
>   formats per field.
>  Hide format tips per role.
>  Hide more format
>   tips link per role.
>  Hide format selection per role per entity.

Comment: Oh sweet, I forgot all about this module.

Answer (score 3):

The D8 port of [Better Formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_formats) seems to have stalled.  A better (sorry, no pun intended) option would probably be [Allowed Formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats).  That seems to be more actively maintained, and has a [stable 8.x-1.1 release](https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats/releases/8.x-1.1).

Enjoy,
-Derek (dww)

Comment: The D8 Contrib Porting Tracker seems to confirm this [on the status page for better_formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/contrib_tracker/issues/2609472#comment-12913570).